# Deleteing a substring buffer is throwing error?

Tags: java, stringbuffer

Today is my first  day in  programming world i am trying to learn java so please excuse me for these sort of question

Deleting a stringbuffer object is throwing error?please help me to fix it my code is below

```
    class Demo 
{
   public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer(); //default 16

       sb.append("abc");
       sb.append("xyz");
       sb.append("123");
       System.out.println("before delete():"+sb);
       sb.delete(3,6);
       System.out.println("after delete():"+sb);
       sb.delete(99);                           //here error please help?
      System.out.println("after delete():"+sb);
  }
}
```

Comment: You are deleting the 99th character which isn't there, what other than an exception did you expect?

Answer (score 1):

There is no method `delete(int)` defined in `StringBuffer` class.

It has to be `delete(int, int)`. The other method which is offered by StringBuffer class is `deleteCharAt(int)`

Also, you string buffer object doesn't have anything at 99th index. Even if you use `deleteCharAt(int)` it is going to throw `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Answer (score 0):

I think there's no delete method with a single argument. You're calling a non-existing method.

[StringBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#delete(int,%20int))